# Java Clock class does not give me the current time

Tags: java, time, clock

I try to use the Clock class to get the current time.

```
public class TestClock {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clock c = Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    System.out.println(c.instant());
  }
}
```

But the problem is that it does not give me the current time, 
but it gives:

> (the current time - 3 hours)

So I decided to be more precise and to specify to the program the city where I live in. (Beirut)

```
public class TestClock {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Beirut");
    Clock c = Clock.system(zone);
    System.out.println(c.instant());
  }
}
```

Also, it gives me:

> (the current time - 3 hours).

So where is the problem?

Note: In Lebanon-Beirut the time +3 Greenwich, is there a relation between this information and my problem?

Comment: An instant has no timezone.

Comment: Use [`ZonedDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-). [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) doesn't have a time zone, or it is in the UTC time zone, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I still have one question: Why we can pass zone as a parameter to the clock objects, while there is no method in the clock class that gives time with time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Erwin Bolwidt pointed out please use `ZonedDateTime` and pass the zone.

```
public class TestClock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Beirut");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

### Result:

```
2019-06-11T10:07:20.447+03:00[Asia/Beirut]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I still have one question: Why we can pass zone as a parameter to the clock objects, while there is no method in the clock class that gives time with time zone?

Comment: Please read about the `Instant` in java official doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html